# In Tableau, how can I create sub-category fields out of an overarching dimension?

Tags: tableau

I have a data set where it's more or less a star schema-like format, but in an Excel file. Don't worry about primary keys setup or any of that unless it significantly matters for answering this question. Here's a sample of the kind of issue I'm facing.

How, from a table like this, would I use Tableau to search by "Cat" and "Dog" as their own fields? In the default Tableau view, they all just show up as "pet," and I can't find any way to seperate the two. I want to set up a chart with quantity of "Cat" on the X-Axis, quantity of "Dog" on the Y-Axis, and then each person graphed as a point relative to how many cats and dogs they have.

No matter what I search, all I find is information about grouping sub-categories,  and I can't find anything about how to create the sub-categories in the first place if they aren't given to you. Could anyone give me a hand?

| Name | Pet | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Sam | Cat | 1 |
| Sam | Dog | 2 |
| Pat | Bird | 3 |
| Bert | Dog | 1 |

Answer (score 1):

You could try the Tableau [Logical Functions](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/functions_functions_logical.htm) in a [calculated field](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/calculations_calculatedfields_formulas.htm).

For example, to calculate the quantity of Cat, you could use:

```
IF [Pet] = 'Cat' THEN SUM([Quantity]) END
```